# How to scale and offset a cubemap using sphere mapping

Tags: texture, shader, glsl, hlsl, uv-mapping

I am trying to scale and repeat a Cubemap with Latitude-Longitude mapping layout just as you would do with classical UV mapping but without any interesting result. This should be used as a skybox.

This comes from the fact that the coordinates are in 3D space and we can't apply this simple formula `texcoord.xy * scale.xy + offset.xy`

How would you handle such features : scaling which involves tiling and offsetting.

```
samplerCUBE _TexCube;
texCUBE(_TexCube, float3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really answer the question but is a workaround. Beware it's hack time :)

Instead of using the `texCUBE` and `samplerCube` I'll be using the `tex2D` method and a simple `sampler` to sample the texture.

As I am using a sphere mesh, I generate 2D UVs like this.

```
float x = atan2(vertex.x, vertex.z) / PI;
x = x / 2.0 + 0.5; // To remap from 0 to 1
float y = vertex.y / 2.0 + 0.5; // Also remap from 0 to 1
float3 color = tex2D(sampler, float2(x, y) * scale.xy + offset.xy);
```

It's a bit hacky but using this I have 2D texture coordinates for my texture.